# Is there a way to match on all variants of an enum in rust?

Tags: rust, enums

Is there something that is equivalent to this:

```rust
enum ABC {
    A(u32),
    B(i32),
    C(f64),
}

fn main() {
    let abc = ABC::A(42);

    match abc {
        _(foo) => foo,
    }
}
```

The reason why I'm asking is that sometimes, I want to use an enum for the different possible types, but most cases I need to handle the data in the enum variants the same exact way.

Comment: can you provide an example of how you are handling them "the same exact way"?

Comment: It looks like you should separate the type from the data, ie you should replace your current enum with a struct having both a value field and a "type" field which would be an enum without value

Comment: An example is in a hashmap, I can't use multiple types for values(and keys too). So I use an enum for the values, and then after accessing them by key, all I want is to use the data in the enum, the same way

Comment: @DenysSéguret I don't get how that would go, could you maybe offer an illustration?

Comment: my intention was that the datatypes should be different, like say type A holds an i32 and type B an f64 ... etc but all can be added to 1. Something of the sort.

Comment: no you can't, there is no sort cut, write a macro if you want.

Comment: With the new context it's possible you'd need a trait and to apply it to u32, i32, 64, but this new question is too vague to be answered in a general way.

Comment: Alright. Though, after changing the question, I regret losing your solution as it was a very useful one. Could we edit the question and at least leave that solution for someone with the same problem but with the same types?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7f6099410007385fd27bbeb514df7d1d but I will not undeleted my answer is irrelevant now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match against all possible variants and perform a common action you can
write a macro for it and reduce code repetition:

```
enum ABC {
    A(u32),
    B(i32),
    C(f64),
}

#[macro_use]
macro_rules! per_letter {
    ($val:expr, $pattern:pat => { $res:expr }) => (
        match $val {
            $crate::ABC::A($pattern) => $res,
            $crate::ABC::B($pattern) => $res,
            $crate::ABC::C($pattern) => $res,
        }
    )
}

impl ABC {
    pub fn print_inner(&self) {
        per_letter!(self, letter => {println!("{}", letter)});
    }
    pub fn print_quad(&self) {
        per_letter!(self, letter => {println!("{}", *letter**letter)});
    }
}
```

Note that this is limited. You can't have multiple possible return types without wrapping them in an enum. But it's still useful if your inner types share a common functionality.

```
fn main() {
    let foo = ABC::A(2);
    foo.print_inner();
    foo.print_quad();
}
```